# Disabling constant RTS and DTR on Serial to usb adapter

Tags: 14.04, usb

I am using a Prolific PL 2303 serial to usb adapter and am using Ubuntu 14.04.  The problem I am having is when the USB to serial adapter is connected, RTS and DTR are constantly on.  This is a problem for me since I am am using RTS and DTR to key a West Mountain Radio Rigblaster Plus, and this keeps it constantly keyed.  How can I disable RTS and DTR to be constantly on?

Answer (score 0):

`stty -F /dev/ttySX crtscts` (modify the /dev/ttySX to match your device). This enables RTS/CTS hardware flow control in the Linux device driver. Then when a DTE (such as a PC) wants to stop the flow into it, it negates RTS. Negated "Request To Send" (-12 volts) means "request NOT to send to me" (stop sending). When the PC is ready for more bytes it asserts RTS (+12 volts) and the flow of bytes to it resumes. Flow control signals are always sent in a direction opposite to the flow of bytes that is being controlled. DCE equipment (modems) works the same way but sends the stop signal out the CTS pin. Thus it's RTS/CTS flow control using 2 lines.

Note that the crtscts command is not POSIX compliant. Depending on your implementation you may have better results with the clocal switch mentioned below.

Here's some other useful control switches from the [man page.](http://gittup.org/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1+stty)

```
   Control settings:
   [-]clocal
          disable modem control signals

   [-]cread
          allow input to be received
```

Sources: `man stty`